# Intellisense auto-completes jQuery $ with _$getActiveXObject

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 RC. Every time I type `$` and then proceed with typing the `(` to start a jQuery selector, Visual Studio is unhelpfully auto completing the statement with  `_$getActiveXObject` which is turning me into a **screaming lunatic**.

Is there a way to disable this? I can't imagine that `_$getActiveXObject` would be used more than jQuery, which baffles me why this would be the default intellisense behavior.

Comment: Yep got that but I don't want to have to press esc every time I type a jQuery selector. That's mental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 has an updated IntelliSense file for jQuery. If you retrieve jQuery via NuGet, you should automatically get it.